# Unable to use method chaining in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

The code looks pretty simple

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) as 'total' FROM table";


// does not work
$total = $conn->query($q)->fetch_assoc()['total']; 



// works
$res1 = $conn->query($qcount_no_admin);
$row1 = $res1->fetch_assoc();
$total = $row1['total'];
```

I get a 500 error (momentarily I'm unable to make errors show, have to talk with the host).

Is this kind of method chaining possible in php mysqli ?

Comment: You are free to write your own implementation.

Comment: You can try `$total = (($conn->query($q))->fetch_assoc())['total']`

Comment: @Nemoden Are you sure this is not possible, because from what I remember I have been able to use chaining on php 7. (Right now I'm using php 5.2, I cannot test with v7)

Comment: @Noman Could you test it?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Still error 500.

Comment: @Lemures: Short hand is supported in PHP 5.4

Comment: Test with multiple version here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2926f8d48ee466156857d8566a7e40516db2002f you can get this working with php 5.4 or greater

Comment: Would be nice to check for errors occasionally though, just assuming your SQL works is a common source of questions on SO.

Comment: @NigelRen You're right, but even if I solved my problem, I would not know the reason. Now I know.

Comment: You should consider setting up a dev environment on your own computer. Much easier to develop on than a live server that you do not control

Comment: @JimL I'm working on a test (dev) VM.

Comment: Oh, your comment about having to speak with the host to show errors confused me then

Comment: @JimL I was just too lazy to fix the error-not-showing problem. I tried to solve it in 10 minutes, could not. The errors won't show in that page only, everywhere else they're shown

Comment: @JimL Plus, this project is in php 5.2, + is not object oriented, + a superweird (old) template engine, no documentation (e.g. If I create a variable in the controller, I **have to** use in in the view, otherwise Error 500.), + no comments in the code whatsoever, + ugly code style, + a project started 10 years ago and finished 6 years ago and never touched since then, + I have no superior able to help me with the code. But still, insert `This is fine` meme :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax should work fine [as far back as PHP 5.4](https://3v4l.org/krWII).

The missing piece in earlier versions isn't the chaining itself, just the ability to dereference an array returned by a function/method. This is known as [function array dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing), and allows you to do things like:

```
function foo() { return ['Hello']; }
echo foo()[0]; // Hello
```

For earlier versions, you will just need to assign to a temporary variable:

```
function foo() { return ['Hello']; }
$result = foo();
echo $result[0]; // Hello
```